# Scala dependent products without pointless casts

Tags: scala, dependent-type

I am using path dependent types in the following way:

```
trait Schema {
  type Repr
}

trait Mapping[A] {
  val schema: Schema
  def reify(repr: schema.Repr): A
  def reflect(value: A): schema.Repr
}

object Mapping {
  implicit def trivialMapping(s: Schema): Mapping[s.Repr] = new Mapping[s.Repr] {
    override final val schema: Schema = s
    override def reify(repr: schema.Repr): s.Repr = repr.asInstanceOf[s.Repr]
    override def reflect(value: s.Repr): schema.Repr = value.asInstanceOf[schema.Repr]
  }
}
```

Note the asInstanceOf in the implementation of reify and reflect. I believe these are pointless, as "schema" is always equal to "s". Is there any idiomatic way to implement this pattern, without type casting? Second question: is there any subtle reason why "s" could be different then "schema" or is it that scalac just doesn't know about value equality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
    override final val schema: Schema = s
```

`Schema` is too general and has an abstract `Repr`. 
Either give it the singleton type of `s` or provide a type refinement that specifies `Repr` to be `s.Repr`.